# how can i get records for last hour from the last record inserted

Tags: mysql, sql

i have session table contains these records:

```
+---------+----------------+-----------+------------------------+ 
|   id    |    session     |    ip     |        login_time      |
+---------+----------------+-----------+------------------------+
|    1    |   fjdjetje5e   | 127.0.0.1 |   2021-01-24 10:02:06  |
|    2    |   rgrdd        | 127.0.0.1 |   2021-01-24 10:10:01  |
|    3    |   hèyth        | 127.0.0.1 |   2021-01-24 10:04:00  |
|    4    |   rwytw4364    | 127.0.0.1 |   2021-01-24 16:08:59  |
|    5    |   iliiu        | 127.0.0.1 |   2021-01-24 16:03:56  |
|    6    |   reuretyre    | 127.0.0.1 |   2021-01-24 16:06:53  |
|    7    |   rthrtrt      | 127.0.0.1 |   2021-01-24 16:05:51  |
|    8    |   66735        | 127.0.0.1 |   2021-01-24 17:09:49  |
|    9    |   ooluh        | 127.0.0.1 |   2021-01-24 18:07:46  |
|    10   |   sdxxs        | 127.0.0.1 |   2021-01-24 18:11:43  |
+---------+----------------+-----------+------------------------+
```

i want to get all records of 1 hour from the last inserted record:

```
//this what i expected
|    9    |   ooluh        | 127.0.0.1 |   2021-01-24 18:07:46  |
|    10   |   sdxxs        | 127.0.0.1 |   2021-01-24 18:11:43  |
```

this what i try

```
SELECT *
FROM session
WHERE login_time >= DATE_SUB(now(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
```

it work only when the time of my computer was approxy of `2021-01-24 18:11:43`

Comment: If you want records from 1 hour of the last inserted record, why use `NOW()` in your query? You need to use time of that record instead. And you'll probably want another condition to ensure the retrieved records are `<=` to be within your range.

Comment: @miken32 yeah, i am stuck in this, how can i use the time of last record to select 1 hour before it with the same query ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM session
WHERE login_time >= (select DATE_SUB(max(login_time),INTERVAL 1 HOUR) from session);
```

You can use something like above.